# Angular CLI "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false"

Tags: angular-cli

I have problem with install Angular CLI

I have installed:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 15.3.0
npm: 7.0.14
os: win32 x64
@angular/cli: 11.0.3
```

but when I want create my project using

```
PS C:\Users\koryt\OneDrive\Desktop\AngularApp\Angular_learning> ng new angular-foodkcal
```

I don't want to create a project and I get it

```
As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release,
which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated
shortly after.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false".

installing ng2
  create .editorconfig
  create README.md
  create src\app\app.component.css
  create src\app\app.component.html
  create src\app\app.component.spec.ts
  create src\app\app.component.ts
  create src\app\app.module.ts
  ...
  create tslint.json
Successfully initialized git.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'karma@1.2.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.10 || 0.12 || 4 || 5 || 6' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.3.0', npm: '7.0.14' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'karma-cli@1.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.10 || 0.12 || 4 || 5 || 6' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.3.0', npm: '7.0.14' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated exists-sync@0.0.3: Please replace with usage of fs.existsSync
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@2.0.5: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
...
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\koryt\angular-foodkcal\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\koryt\angular-foodkcal\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\koryt\angular-foodkcal\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:192:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\koryt\\angular-foodkcal\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\koryt\angular-foodkcal\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\koryt\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-06T17_27_07_338Z-debug.log
```

Package install failed, see above.

How I can fix this?

Comment: You have *angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3* **and** *@angular/cli: 11.0.3* installed? You should start by removing the old version (angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3) from your system.

Comment: Ow, you have right :D thank you for your help